# SQL Server how to turn number of rows to column value?

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I have three rows return from a table as below:

```
select ID 
from service
```

Results:

```
ID 
--
1 
2
3
```

How can I return output like below:

```
count  |    IDs 
-------+----------
3      |    1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```
select (select Count(*) from service)+' | '+ SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + s.FirstName 
        FROM Employee s
        ORDER BY s.FirstName FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, ''
) AS Employees)
```

Comment: @apple, mark this as the answer since it answered your question.

Comment: @apple Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be work with `stuff()` function then you will no need to `subquery` for count of ids

```
select count(1) count,
       stuff(
             (select ','+cast(id as varchar) from table for xml path('')),
             1,1,'') Ids
from table
```